# Disable archiving of old posts?

Tags: posts, archives

I need to disable archiving.  We want to have all posts, no matter how old, remain in the roll with the newer posts even if you have to page back to get to them.

I've been searching, and most of what I've turned up is how to simply disable *archive pages*. I'm unclear if this will have the desired effect of keeping the posts in the main blogroll.

Comment: Please provide more information on your problem, cause it´s not really clear. Posts normally stay on a paginated frontpage, so what´s the problem?

Comment: I had inherited this site, so I am a little confused.  The author apparently is using "list category posts" plugin.  So I am able to fix it through the shortcode.  Thanks, it was your mention of "paginated" that caused me to figure it out.

Comment: You´re welcome, glad I could help.